# Probability $P\{\min{X_1,X_2}\leq X_3\}$?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables, exponential-distribution

Let $X_1, X_2$ and $X_3$ exponential random variables with the same parameter $\beta$?

The PDF and CDF of $X_i$ are 
$$
f_{X_i}(x)=\beta e^{-x \beta},
$$
$$
F_{X_i}(x)=1-e^{-x \beta}.
$$

The PDF and CDF of $Y=\min\{X_1,X_2\}$ are 
$$
f_{Y}(y)=2\beta e^{-2\beta y},
$$
$$
F_{Y}(y)=1-e^{-2\beta y}.
$$
I would lieke to find the probability that 
$$
P\Big\{\min\{X_1,X_2\}\leq X_3\Big\},
$$
and the probability 
$$
P\Big\{\min\{X_1,X_2\}> X_3\Big\}.
$$
I use the following steps 
\begin{align}
P\Big\{\min\{X_1,X_2\}\leq X_3\Big\}&=P\Big\{Y\leq X_3\Big\}\\
&=\int_{x_3=0}^{\infty}\left(\int_{y=0}^{x_3}f_Y(y)dy\right)f_{X_3}(x_3)dx_3\\
&=\int_{x_3=0}^{\infty}F_y(x_3)f_{X_3}(x_3)dx_3\\
&=1-\int_{x_3=0}^{\infty}e^{-2\beta x_3}\beta e^{-\beta x_3}dx_3\\
&=1-\beta\int_{x_3=0}^{\infty}e^{-3\beta x_3}dx_3\\
&=1-\frac{\beta}{3\beta}\\
&=2/3.
\end{align}
For 
$$
P\Big\{\min\{X_1,X_2\}> X_3\Big\}=1-P\Big\{\min\{X_1,X_2\}\leq X_3\Big\}=1/3.
$$

IS my derivation true?

Thanks.

Comment: Incidentally, there is in fact an easier way to obtain the answer: you effectively want the probability that $X_3$ is either "first" or "second" if we sort in order. By symmetry,  $X_3$ is equally likely to be "first", "second", or "third", so there is a 2 in 3 chance that it is first or second. In other words, the answer is $2/3$. This will be true as long as are $X_1,X_2, X_3$ are iid (they don't have to be exponentially distributed).

Comment: Can I just add that your calculations are indeed correct. May I ask, why were you suspicious something might be wrong with your solution?

Comment: Because I try To use in other things, and it dose not works.